# Http post SAML request ADFS

Tags: http, post, saml, adfs

I am attempting to architect a Web Sso solution. Part of that involves an http post to a client's ADFS server. I know my form needs to contain a field named "sAMLRequest" but is there anything else i need to submit. Right now all I'm getting from the ADFS server is a stock error with little clue as to the underlying issue

Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlMessageException: MSIS7015: This request does not contain the expected protocol message or incorrect protocol parameters were found according to the HTTP SAML protocol bindings.

Answer (score 0):

SAMLRequest field needs to be Base64 but not urlendcoded then ADFS will recognize it, additionally a RelayState field can be specified to maintain state